Celery Worker in C++ using Redis
What is a correct approach to creating a Celery worker in C++ using Redis as the message broker?
In this blog post, the author describes a Celery worker that runs tasks queued on RabbitMQ (AMQP). The associated code is here.  The worker routine loops, reading Celery messages and sending an acknowledgment.
With Redis as the Celery message broker, can one also simply loop and consume messages posted to the Redis queue?  How does one handle acknowledgments to Celery?

They answer is yes, as long as you follow the protocol. There are multiple implementations including Go, PHP and Rust... None of them fully functional though.
